# How much load on a node is too much?

Tags: linux, cassandra, load, cpu-usage, datastax

We have 10 node Cassandra cluster and would like to monitor Load(CPU) .
The OpsCenter shows the load on nodes ranges from 0 to 20s and sometimes it goes in 50s and 60s . But normally its below 25 .
We just want to understand how much should be considered alarming ?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok until you don't have performance issues/timeouts.

Going higher than 80% is not recommended as you don't have time to react. Also consider checking your 60% spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your hardware and installation.

I recommend doing stress-testing of your system. Because we don't know how many writes and reads you are doing. You need reserve one core for linux and keep load 80%.